# GXT TextArea does not show it's value

Tags: gxt

I'm working on a legacy GXT (2.2.4) project and I stumbled in a strange behavior. A form panel (`com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.form.FormPanel`) with a textarea (`com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.form.TextArea`) element. I use formbinding mechanism with form panel. Every bean's data is showed into the form's field expect that for text area which remain blank. Debug reveal that text area is storing bean's value correctly and when I change this value I also change the bean value, but it's not showing the value. Even if I set the value by `setValue(...)` textarea field remains blank. I'm not so new with GXT but I never ran into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was about an asynchronous event which set my textarea's value. Such a waste of time.